# ValueError :must start with a character '-'

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse, face-detection

```
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
ap=argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i","D:\python learning\IMG_20130614_000526.jpg",required=True,help="path to input image")
ap.add_argument("-p","D:\python learning\deep-learning-face-detection\deploy.prototxt.txt",required=True,help="path to Caffe 'deploy' prototxt file")
ap.add_argument("-m","D:\python learning\deep-learning-face-detection\res10_300x300_ssd_iter_140000.caffemodel",required=True,help="path to Caffe pretrained model")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence",type=float,default=0.5,help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")
args=vars(ap.parse_args())
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python learning\detectfaces.py", line 6, in <module>
    ap.add_argument("-p","D:\python learning\deep-learning-face-detection\deploy.prototxt.txt",required=True,help="path to Caffe 'deploy' prototxt file")
  File "C:\Users\RAJKUMAR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\argparse.py", line 1320, in add_argument
    kwargs = self._get_optional_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\RAJKUMAR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\argparse.py", line 1451, in _get_optional_kwargs
    raise ValueError(msg % args)
ValueError: invalid option string 'D:\\python learning\\deep-learning-face-detection\\deploy.prototxt.txt': must start with a character '-'
>>>
```

Comment: The positional arguments to `add_argument` are argument names given on the command line, like you have correctly for `"--confidence"`. You seem to be trying to add argument values, which is a misunderstanding of how argparse works. See [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) for how to use this library.

Comment: I have edited the code and removed the argument values for image,prototxt and model , but now i am getting this error."usage: detectfaces.py [-h] -i IMAGE -p PROTOTXT -m MODEL [-c CONFIDENCE]
detectfaces.py: error: the following arguments are required: -i/--image, -p/--prototxt, -m/--model"

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the paths you are supplying (for example `"D:\python learning\IMG_20130614_000526.jpg"`) are intended as default values for the arguments `-i`, `-p-`, `-m`. If that is what you are trying to do, specify them as defaults. Your code is specifying them as *argument names* (like `--confidence`) which is why `argparse` is telling you they must begin with a hyphen.

For example:

```
ap.add_argument("-i", "--input_image", required=True, help="path to input image", default=r"D:\python learning\IMG_20130614_000526.jpg")
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2
ap=argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i","--input_image",required=True,help="path to input image")
ap.add_argument("-p","--deploy_file_path",required=True,help="path to Caffe 'deploy' prototxt file")
ap.add_argument("-m","--model",required=True,help="path to Caffe pretrained model")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence",type=float,default=0.5,help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")
args=vars(ap.parse_args())
```

Comment: usage: detectfaces.py [-h] -i INPUT_IMAGE -p DEPLOY_FILE_PATH -m MODEL [-c CONFIDENCE]
detectfaces.py: error: the following arguments are required: -i/--input_image, -p/--deploy_file_path, -m/--model

Comment: You made the options compulsory by adding `required=True` so you need to pass those parameters which are compalsory..